# Can Davenport's estimate be extended to cubic polynomials with non-zero discriminant?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

In 1961 Davenport showed that $H$ large enough there is a constant $c > 0$ such that
$$
\sum \lvert D(P) \rvert^{-1/2} < c H^2
$$
where the sum is taken over the irreducible polynomials of degree $3$ with integer coefficients and height bounded by $H$. Here $D(P)$ denotes the discriminant of the polynomial $P$.

In the introduction he mentions that the irreducibility condition is only a matter of convenience, but he doesn't explicitly state that this can be relaxed. Furthermore, as far as I can tell the results on which the proof is based are only stated for irreducible forms.

So, my question is: does the above estimate holds when the sum is taken over polynomials with $D(P) \neq 0$, instead of just irreducible polynomials?

---

[1] Davenport, H. (1961). A note on binary cubic forms. Mathematika, 8(1), 58-62. [doi:10.1112/S0025579300002138](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300002138)

Comment: You forgot to tell us what $D$ stands for.

Comment: Oh, right. $D(P)$ stands for the discriminant of the polynomial $P$.

Comment: The answer is surely yes, as I suspect Davenport's argument will hold verbatim by replacing the assumption "irreducible" with "having non-zero discriminant".